# How do I install latest/later gcc on cygwin?

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, exe, bin

Is there somewhere where I can just download the latest gcc.exe binaries for Windows and place them inside /bin, just like other compilers (bcc/msc)?

I'd try not to touch http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_a_newer_version_of_GCC,

Answer (score 0):

What I did was install

[Ruben’s updated build](http://sf.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb)

Example

```
gcc-4.8-release
```

Comment: Ah, I found ftp://ftp.equation.com/gcc/ instead and installed 64-bit, select install path to cygwin directory and it worked too. Thanks.